# Annoying problem with the microphone when muted

Tags: microphone, audio-recording

I got a new HyperX Cloud headphone and I cant find a solution for a problem what I have when I mute the microphone using the switch (which disconnect the microphone completely), it makes a very annoying, high pitched noise until I unmute it, I recorded it but it sounds not so annoying in the recording https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33926727/Untitled.wma . Any idea what causes this ? I tried it on a different pc and it works perfectly there, could it be a bad ground (but there is almost no static when using the microphone) or it is something else wrong with my audio card ?

Comment: Probably, the mute switch simply leaves the mic wire "dangling" instead of properly shorting it against ground; this makes the line very susceptible to any interference from the computer's power supply etc.. Not much reasonably effective you can do about this, externally... either re-wire the switch, to don't use it at all (mute in software or some extra mixing device).

Comment: I have some experience with repairing electronics, so I could rewire it but I dont know what to short to ground, the 5v to ground or the signal line ? and what resistance should I use to short it to the ground ?

Comment: Well, that headset claims to use A-B powering (Tonaderspeisung... a bit weird, this is supposed to be outdated for decades) rather than proper phantom power / PiP, which would mean there's actually just two wires to be considered. You don't short against ground, but the signal + and - against one another. (Actually this is the same you'd do for phantom power, I was talking nonsense above – only, phantom doesn't give you a nasty loud "plop" when switching on or off which you probably _will_ get when shorting that microphone, which may be the reason why they chose to just not to short it).

Comment: So should I just short the middle pin with the top pin without a resistance and it will work ? There is also a button on the back of the control box which is for answering phone calls, and from what I remember, buttons like those work by shorting the microphone line, so if I rewire the switch to do the same thing like the button, it should be fine ? the button also makes a loud pop if pressed.

Comment: I think that that should work somehow, but don't blame me if it doesn't... I'd need to try it myself to be sure.